# Cant access values inside my iFrame it gives me permission denied

Tags: javascript, iframe, permissions, cross-domain

I cant access values inside my iFrame it gives me permission denied. I have access on both pages (parent and child).

I added the following javascript line on both pages:

document.domain = "sub.domain.com";

but firebug gives me :
Illegal document.domain value

and when i try to access element inside the iFrame it prompts : Permission denied for http://sub1.domain1.com to call method Location.toString on http://sub2.domain2.com

Thanks

Comment: Cross-Domain Scripting is not allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only set document.domain to a superdomain of the pages actual domain, not an entirely different one (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain). So if you set up 1.sub.domain.com and 2.sub.domain.com you should be able to set document.domain on both of them to sub.domain.com and that should work.

Comment: do you mean that i can change x.example.com to y.exmaple.com but i cant change it to y.example2.com ?

Comment: Not quite. You can only change x.example.com to example.com. You can basically only strip existing parts off of the domain, not add any new ones. example2.com or sub.domain.com in your setup aren't part of the original domain, so can't be added in.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Domain Scripting is not allowed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Not working:

```
http://sub1.domain1.com
http://sub2.domain2.com
```

Working:

```
http://sub1.domain1.com
http://sub2.domain1.com
```

Comment: Yes i know, I want to set them to the same domain, but the (document.domain = "domain.com") is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Some hacks for Cross domain communication with iframes ~> http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: I have went through it before